Can clang-17-dev be installed on debian bullseye?
I want to use cl-bindgen and it depends on libclang-17.so
I am on a x86_64 debian bullseye machine.
After several attempts, I seem unable to install clang-17-dev, which supposedly has libclang-17.so.
Any tips on how I can install it?
I tried adding the debian sid unstable branch to my apt configuration but it still did not work.

you will need to build cl-bindgen (whatever that is) against the version of libglang on your platform anyways, so it's surprising that you have a binary version that tells you that it needs a specific .so file. This points to you just copying binaries for another system to your system; that won't work out, especially if the name of thing suggests it's a binding creater of some sort. You will need to add the installation method you chose for cl-bindgen to your question, and investigate whether that is a recommended method.

@MarcusMüller cl-bindgen is (cough) python and it uses some other (cough cough) python package, which ... recurse at will... eventually uses a python packge which depends on clang-17.

so, how did you install these packages???

@MarcusMüller With the glorious python package manager thing called... pip? I don't really use Python and I do not plan to. The tool was supposed to create ffi bindings for c code so it can be accessed in Common Lisp. And once I hit this road block, I simply did the FFI code myself.

yeah that seems pretty sensible of you.
